# Filter AT+CSQ response

Tags: c, arduino-uno

I am working on a project and am using Arduino UNO and some other components. I need some communication and have employed a Huawei MU509 module. I haven't employed GSM library for varied reasons, I need to check the signal strength at an interval of 5sec, I use  `AT+CSQ` and i get something like the following response which is ok.

`AT+CSQ`

`+CSQ: 9,99`

`OK`

The challenge comes in when i want to display this info in a more readable format, probably a percentage will work.
I have a function that takes the input of the format `+CSQ: 9,99` and returns 9 which i can handle very nicely, however my module responds in this format

-echos the command

-followed by response

-OK

meaning my function wont figure out the actual input.
I'm requesting a workaround to filter this output and get the response that would fit my function, or rather a solution that would simply provide me with the signal strength in a format that i can convert to percentage and display to the user.

Comment: Please show us your current effort and tell us, where **exactly** you have a problem. Hint: The echo starts with "at" or "AT" while the actual output is a line starting with "+"

Comment: You might avoid the echo with a "ATE0" command on that AT channel.

Comment: @Gerhardh, if i can shut the echo the its better, let me add the actual code in a moment.